# how to restore/recover deleted tab of a flow in node-red?

Tags: tabs, node-red

I am working on a big project in node-red. And there are a lot of tabs which contains flows. I accidentally deleted a tab and now it's gone. How can I restore/Recover that deleted tab? Any little help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you have not hit deploy yet, you can get the tab back by hitting ctrl-z (undo)

If you have hit deploy, but only once then there should be a backup of the last version of the flow in your userDir as a hidden file called `.flow_name.json.backup`

Comment: Thank you guys for your kind responses. I have deployed more than once. So it's gone. Now I have to do it again. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If you have not hit the Deploy button, then you can use Ctrl-Z to undo the delete of the tab.

If you have deployed the change, then you'll need to revert to a backup. Node-RED keeps *one* backup of the flow file for you. Check the node-red startup log for the name of the flow file it is using. Look in that directory for a file with the same name but with 'backup' in it.

If you have deployed more than once, then your deleted tab is gone.